# Why does bitbake ignore CFLAGS in my makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, bitbake, openembedded

My application's makefile adds a couple things to CFLAGS as follows:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -std=gnu99
```

When I build the application with OpenEmbedded BitBake however, BitBake is apparently ignoring the CFLAGS variable from the makefile.

I found that adding the following line in the application's recipe causes the flags to be used during a build via BitBake:

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "CFLAGS='-Wall -std=gnu99'"
```

Why does BitBake ignore the CFLAGS from the makefile like this? Also, is there a better solution than adding the line above to recipe?

I'd prefer that the makefile's CFLAGS just be used in order to eliminate the redundancy.

Comment: Is bitbake using the makefile at all? Does it explicitly override `CFLAGS` on the command line when it runs `make`?

Comment: This is confusing: bitbake uses `recipe` files, not the `makefile`. Why are you using bitbake?  If you have a makefile, use gnu make.

Comment: @EtanReisner Bitbake does use the makefile, but as far as I can tell it's not explicitly overriding CFLAGS on the command line when running make.

Comment: @chqrlie The recipe file describes to BitBake how to build the application. The makefile is being utilized, but CFLAGS in particular is for some reason being ignored. I have to use BitBake as it's part of the OpenEmbedded based build system I use for cross-compiling for an embedded system.

Comment: it is highly probable that bitbake passes its own value of `CFLAGS` to `make` in a way that makes `make` ignore the value set in the Makefile, such as on `make`s command line.  You can verify this with some sort of verbose mode.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, `bitbake.conf` contains `EXTRA_OEMAKE = "-e MAKEFLAGS="` which is passed to the make command when its run (see `base.bbclass`, which runs `${MAKE} ${EXTRA_OEMAKE} "$@"`).

The `-e` option to make means that environment variables override makefiles (from `make --help`). You'll also notice that `bitbake.conf` sets `export CFLAGS = "${TARGET_CFLAGS}"` amongst several other exported variables, so `CFLAGS` is set in the environment.

The reason it does this is that there are some compiler flags which are important whilst cross compiling and in general, the system has a better idea of what to use than the `Makefile` does. This does sometimes fail as you've found.

You could remove the `-e` option from `EXTRA_OEMAKE` but you run the risk of other key variables not being set correct (e.g. would it find the cross compiler). Another slightly cleaner solution might be to add to `TARGET_CFLAGS`, e.g.:

```
TARGET_CFLAGS += "-Wall -std=gnu99"
```

Unfortunately there is likely no perfect solution here however hopefully this helps understand why it does what it does.

Comment: Note that bitbake.conf now has `EXTRA_OEMAKE = ""`. See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-2.1-makefile-environment-changes